# Error in GDCprepare(query_cnv) : There are samples duplicated. We will not be able to prepare it

Tags: r

I used R code to create function to find the rows without duplicated rows.

```
 View(getResults(query_cnv))
 
 #query_results <- getResults(query_cnv_with_data_type)
#query_cnv <- GDCquery(project =  cancer_type,
                      #data.category = "Copy Number Variation",
                     # data.type = "Gene Level Copy Number Scores")
query_results<- getResults(query_cnv)
#print(query_results)
View(query_results)
unique_results <- unique(query_results)
View(unique_results)
#############################################################################################################
GDCdownload(query_cnv)
print(query_cnv)
##########################################################################################

# 查看前几行

data_cnv <- GDCprepare(query_cnv)

data_cnv_unique <- data_cnv[!duplicated(data_cnv$cases), ]
```

The error information is :
There is duplicated items but I don't know how to filter the information and create unique rows.

```
|920  |TCGA-ZF-A9RG-01A-21D-A42D-01;TCGA-ZF-A9RG-10A-01D-A42G-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|1014 |TCGA-ZF-A9RG-01A-21D-A42D-01;TCGA-ZF-A9RG-10A-01D-A42G-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|1100 |TCGA-ZF-A9RL-01A-11D-A38F-01;TCGA-ZF-A9RL-10A-01D-A38I-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|1102 |TCGA-ZF-A9RL-01A-11D-A38F-01;TCGA-ZF-A9RL-10A-01D-A38I-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|139  |TCGA-ZF-A9RM-01A-11D-A38F-01;TCGA-ZF-A9RM-10A-01D-A38I-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|1182 |TCGA-ZF-A9RM-01A-11D-A38F-01;TCGA-ZF-A9RM-10A-01D-A38I-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|130  |TCGA-ZF-A9RN-10A-01D-A42G-01;TCGA-ZF-A9RN-01A-11D-A42D-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|175  |TCGA-ZF-A9RN-10A-01D-A42G-01;TCGA-ZF-A9RN-01A-11D-A42D-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|878  |TCGA-ZF-AA4N-10A-01D-A38I-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4N-01A-11D-A38F-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|1091 |TCGA-ZF-AA4N-10A-01D-A38I-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4N-01A-11D-A38F-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|261  |TCGA-ZF-AA4R-10A-01D-A38I-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4R-01A-11D-A38F-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|1140 |TCGA-ZF-AA4R-10A-01D-A38I-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4R-01A-11D-A38F-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|929  |TCGA-ZF-AA4T-10A-01D-A38I-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4T-01A-11D-A38F-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|930  |TCGA-ZF-AA4T-10A-01D-A38I-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4T-01A-11D-A38F-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|83   |TCGA-ZF-AA4U-10A-01D-A38I-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4U-01A-11D-A38F-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|1028 |TCGA-ZF-AA4U-10A-01D-A38I-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4U-01A-11D-A38F-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|461  |TCGA-ZF-AA4V-01A-11D-A38F-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4V-10A-01D-A38I-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|1161 |TCGA-ZF-AA4V-01A-11D-A38F-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4V-10A-01D-A38I-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|101  |TCGA-ZF-AA4W-01A-12D-A38F-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4W-10A-01D-A38I-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|197  |TCGA-ZF-AA4W-01A-12D-A38F-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4W-10A-01D-A38I-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|332  |TCGA-ZF-AA4X-10A-01D-A38I-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4X-01A-11D-A38F-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|491  |TCGA-ZF-AA4X-10A-01D-A38I-01;TCGA-ZF-AA4X-01A-11D-A38F-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|819  |TCGA-ZF-AA51-01A-21D-A390-01;TCGA-ZF-AA51-10A-01D-A393-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|919  |TCGA-ZF-AA51-01A-21D-A390-01;TCGA-ZF-AA51-10A-01D-A393-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|163  |TCGA-ZF-AA52-01A-12D-A390-01;TCGA-ZF-AA52-10A-01D-A393-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|576  |TCGA-ZF-AA52-01A-12D-A390-01;TCGA-ZF-AA52-10A-01D-A393-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|905  |TCGA-ZF-AA53-10A-01D-A393-01;TCGA-ZF-AA53-01A-11D-A390-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|908  |TCGA-ZF-AA53-10A-01D-A393-01;TCGA-ZF-AA53-01A-11D-A390-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|282  |TCGA-ZF-AA54-01A-11D-A390-01;TCGA-ZF-AA54-10A-01D-A393-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|449  |TCGA-ZF-AA54-01A-11D-A390-01;TCGA-ZF-AA54-10A-01D-A393-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|341  |TCGA-ZF-AA56-10A-01D-A393-01;TCGA-ZF-AA56-01A-31D-A390-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|499  |TCGA-ZF-AA56-10A-01D-A393-01;TCGA-ZF-AA56-01A-31D-A390-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|734  |TCGA-ZF-AA58-10A-01D-A42G-01;TCGA-ZF-AA58-01A-12D-A42D-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|736  |TCGA-ZF-AA58-10A-01D-A42G-01;TCGA-ZF-AA58-01A-12D-A42D-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|758  |TCGA-ZF-AA5H-10A-01D-A393-01;TCGA-ZF-AA5H-01A-11D-A390-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|805  |TCGA-ZF-AA5H-10A-01D-A393-01;TCGA-ZF-AA5H-01A-11D-A390-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|359  |TCGA-ZF-AA5N-10A-01D-A42G-01;TCGA-ZF-AA5N-01A-11D-A42D-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|518  |TCGA-ZF-AA5N-10A-01D-A42G-01;TCGA-ZF-AA5N-01A-11D-A42D-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
|766  |TCGA-ZF-AA5P-10A-01D-A393-01;TCGA-ZF-AA5P-01A-11D-A390-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT3                 |
|866  |TCGA-ZF-AA5P-10A-01D-A393-01;TCGA-ZF-AA5P-01A-11D-A390-01 |Genotyping Array      |ASCAT2                 |
```

Error in GDCprepare(query_cnv) :
There are samples duplicated. We will not be able to prepare it

There is duplicated items but I don't know how to filter the information and create unique rows.

How could I solve the problem?